# How can I simulate a 'moving' location in Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: xcode, swift, location

Trying to extract some moving location data while training in Swift, and the simulator now only has fixed locations (London, New York etc).

I think you used to be able to simulate moving via car or cycle.

Is it possible to simulate a moving location?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simulate a moving location go to
in iOS Simulator settings select below menu(make sure your map is displaying on simulator first then do as below).

Debug -> Location -> Select "City Bicycle Ride" or "Freeway Drive"

[image]

Comment: Now if feel silly, I was using the debug menu in Xcode, not the simulator.

Comment: @Mark Lesbirel if my post helped you please mark it as Answered.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Shiva Kumar - Although I made an error in using the menu in xCode looking at it again the menu UI is confusing as they are the same menu item descriptions. Anyway, thanks again!